# cannot build memory sanitizer instrumented libc++ that link against only compile-rt (no libgcc)?

Tags: cmake, llvm, libc++, memory-sanitizer, msan

I want to use c++ memory sanitizer(msan) on a code repo with llvm toolchain (libc++, libunwind, compiler-rt, clang ...). so the first thing i need to do is to build msan-instrumented libc++.

From [MemorySanitizerLibcxxHowTo](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizerLibcxxHowTo), i need to build libc++ with option `-DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER=Memory` or `-DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER=MemoryWithOrigin`.

From [assembling a complete llvm toolchain](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Toolchain.html#compiler-rt-llvm), in the `LLVM’s compiler runtime library` section

> If using libc++ and/or libc++abi, you may need to configure them to use compiler-rt rather than libgcc_s by passing -DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES and/or -DLIBCXXABI_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES to cmake. Otherwise, you may end up with both runtime libraries linked into your program (this is typically harmless, but wasteful).

Since i'm aiming for a full llvm toolchain, i think i should add `-DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES` and `-DLIBCXXABI_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES`

So i use the scripts below to download libcxx and libcxxabi and create expected dir layout and run the build.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 file_dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
 num_of_processors=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -c ^processor)

 cd $file_dir
 svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
 (cd llvm/projects && svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk libcxx)
 (cd llvm/projects && svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxxabi/trunk libcxxabi)

 export CC=clang
 export CXX=clang++

 [ -d build ] && rm -rf build
 mkdir -p build && cd build
 cmake ../llvm -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.. \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER=Memory \
-DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
-DLIBCXXABI_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES
 make install-libcxx install-libcxxabi -j$num_of_processors
```

The error i get is:

```
-- Performing Test LIBCXX_SUPPORTS_STD_COLON_CXX11_FLAG - Failed
CMake Error at projects/libcxx/CMakeLists.txt:538 (message):
  C++11 or greater is required but the compiler does not support c++11

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "~/libcxx- 
msan/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "~/libcxx- 
msan/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This erro only happens when `-DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER=Memory` and `-DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES` both exists. Removing either of them will fix the problem.

Is there any way i can fix the problem and keep both options (msan and compiler rt)? Thanks in advance!